# viewBox on svg <image> tag has no effect

Tags: svg

The MDN documentation states [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox#Elements) that `<image>` is one of the elements which can have a viewbox.
For me this makes totally sense. Dislaying only a partial image is often a really food feature.

However, it seems like FF as well as Chrome completely ignore a viewBox on image elements.

Here is a simple example which might you try:

```html
<svg width="400" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 600">
 <defs></defs>
 <image width="400" height="600" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Deadtree-mj.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="100 0 200 200"></image>
</svg>
```

**Why is that so?** Is MDN wrong? Or just not implemented?

Comment: Why, because the SVG specification does not support it: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement or https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#InterfaceSVGImageElement

Comment: Looks like nobody used it any it was removed in SVG2. Its a shame - such a useful feature...

Comment: I've corrected MDN. SVG 1.1 is talking about viewBox on the content (where the content is SVG), not viewBox on the element

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. You might add this as answer which I can accept then.

Comment: I've just voted to close this. It doesn't really make that much sense any more now that I've fixed MDN.